# MYSQL querying records for all databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL with a few database instances. Each database is identical with the same table structure but different data stored.

For example:
Database `db1` has a table `db1.client` and columns `db1.client.Id`, `db1.client.Name`, `db1.client.Address`

Database `db2` has a table `db2.client` and columns `db2.client.Id`, `db2.client.Name`, `db2.client.Address`

Database `db3` has a table `db3.client` and columns `db3.client.Id`, `db3.client.Name`, `db3.client.Address`

I would like to query and list every single database and display the name and address for each respective client table.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they all in different *databases*, or different tables *within* the one database?

If the latter, you can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) to string your queries together, e.g.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Address
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, Name, Address
FROM table2
```

If the former (each table is in a different database) you will have to modify with database names as such:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Address
FROM db1.table
UNION
SELECT Id, Name, Address
FROM db2.table
```

Comment: It is the latter option for me. Thanks for the suggestion. What if my databases span to say, a dozen? Can I use a loop for every single database instead of manually selecting each database? Do I need to get involved in stored procedures?

Comment: I think you have to write the one query for each database (you could always generate the query string on the code side).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [mySQL Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) docs.

```
(SELECT name, address, ... FROM db1.client)
UNION
(SELECT name, address, ... FROM db2.client)
UNION
(SELECT name, address, ... FROM db3.client)
```